# Dart: How to iterate over objects in an array in a nested Map?

Tags: flutter, dart, map-function, nested-map

This is the current state of the Map data structure that I am working with in Dart:

```
Map database = {
    'campusConnect': {
        'hashtags': [
             {
                 'id': 4908504398, 
                 'title': '#NeverGiveUp!', 
                 'author': 'ABC',  
             }, 
             {
                  'id': 430805, 
                 'title': '#ItAlwaysTakesTime', 
                 'author': 'XYZ'
             }
         ]
     }
};
```

I want to go over the hashtags array. Iterating over each object in that array, I want to compare the 'id' field with some number that I already have. How do I do it?

So far, this is what I have tried doing:

```
database['campusConnect']['hashtags'].map( (item) {
    print('I am here ...');
    if (item['id'] == hashtagId) {
        print(item['title']);
    }
});
```

I have no idea why, but it gives me no error and does not work at the same time. When I run it, it does not even print "I am here ...".

Notice the identifier "hashtagId" in the if block:

```
if (item['id'] == hashtagId) { ... }
```

This is being passed in the function as an argument. For simplicity, I have not show the function, but assume that this is an int-type parameter I am receiving

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: try `(database['campusConnect']['hashtags'] as List).map( (item) {...}` and wrap that inside a try catch to start seeing the errors. Let us try to get more info

Comment: This is your real code? If so, you defined `hashTags` in the map and `hashtags` when calling the map

Comment: @croxx5f still the problem persists. It does not even print "I am here ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is smart enough to skip the code that does nothing. In your case, you are not using the result of `map()` function. Try to change it with `forEach()` and fix `hashTags` typo

```
  database['campusConnect']['hashTags'].forEach((item) {
    print('I am here ...');
    if (item['id'] == hashtagId) {
      print(item['title']);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method will solve your question.

```dart
  void test(){
    final hashTags = database['campusConnect']['hashTags'];
    if(hashTags is List){
      for(var i=0; i<hashTags.length; i++){
        final id = hashTags[i]['id'];
        if(id == hashtagId){
          // do something
        }
      }
    }
  }
```